# How to save a link clicked in the email for redirect?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I apologize for the title is not so clear, but I will try to be better explaining. Basically I created a program that allows customers to an industry to make appointments through the web. This is working well but the main problem is the link sent via email. If you click this link, the user can change the appointment only if the user is logged in to the system. In fact, if the user has not logged in it is reported (by the email link) to the login page. So basically will:

**Email link:** `http:\www.website.com\Application\index\[appointment_hash]`
**Redirect link:** `http\www.website.com\Application\`

Now the problem is that once logged I would redirect the user to the first link (`email link`) to load the details of the appointment. I'm working with CodeIgniter and I thought of the sessions, but considering that the user is not logged in I can not save any session, and then the link is lost anyway. There are many sites like Amazon and the like that save the link to an article even if you are not logged then ricaricaro later .. How can you do this? Hint?

Comment: you can either use the HTTP referer (warning: this can be faked), or by changing the design: send the suer to the login page with a parameter to identify your target, and redirect if login credentials are present

Comment: Why can't you save the link to a session despite not being logged in?

Comment: You can use session even the user is not logged in

Comment: why do you want save the session before login, you will not redirect the user to his appointment until he log in, when he login you will create the session then redirect to appointment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I use `$this->session->set_userdata('referrer', current_url());` in my controller. After user log in, I check whether the 'referrer' userdata is exist, if it is, I redirect the user to the referrer url. If not I redirect to the dashboard/index.

Comment: Uhm so I can use the session before the user start own session? The problem is solved so.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue for my email alert module. I have solved by passing user id and redirecting link in get method in url with encryption.

in case you can pass encrypted user id and encrypted email link in email.
and with the help of user id you can auto login that user.
so you can solve your autologin option.